# How can I check what slows down my website?

Tags: wordpress, web

My [website](http://www.mamou-mani.com) takes around 15+sec to load. How can I find what slows it down so much?

Comment: use firebug's net tab to check the time of loading all the files. and i don't find this website is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have developed the website then you are the best person to asnwer this question. If you haven't then you might want to look at the [YSLOW](http://yslow.org/) addon for firefox developed by Yahoo

> **Web Performance Best Practices and Rules**
>
> Yahoo!’s Exceptional Performance team has identified 34 rules that
>   affect web page performance. YSlow’s web page analysis is based on the
>   23 of these 34 rules that are testable. Click each performance rule
>   below to see the details.

http://yslow.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools to check your site for performance problems, for example I use Pagespeed from Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome -> web developer tools and check "Network" part to see what elements slowing You down. Also You will see some errors in code, missing files etc.

For me it takes 5 sec to load, so it is not that bad.

Think also about total weight of the site. 5mb is a little bit high IMO.